# Unable to open project in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open a project in VS Code. But I also have the same project open in IntelliJ in my laptop. Is it not possible to open a project in two different IDEs at the same time?

I am able to open other projects in vs code, but if I already have a project open intellij, I cannot open that in vs code. Is this not allowed in VS code?

Should I change anything in the settings of VS code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the header "Explorer" in the Explorer sidebar where your open folder(s) usually appear. Two options, "Open Editors" and "Folders" will appear. Click "Folders" to make it checked and your folders will appear.